# Ler XML Delphi (Iteração entre Itens da Nota Fiscal)

Tags: delphi, xml, nfe

Boa tarde, pessoal.
Estou com o seguinte problema.
Tenho um xml de NFe que pode ter 1 ou mais produtos e preciso ler cada produto desse arquivo.
A Estrutura do XML é a seguinte

```
-<det nItem="1">
  -<prod>
    <cProd>177</cProd>
    <cEAN>SEM GTIN</cEAN>
    <xProd>SCH1</xProd>
    <NCM>96072000</NCM>
    <CFOP>6102</CFOP>
    <uCom>MT</uCom>
    <qCom>409.8400</qCom>
    <vUnCom>1.9600000000</vUnCom>
    <vProd>803.29</vProd>
    <cEANTrib>SEM GTIN</cEANTrib>
    <uTrib>MT</uTrib>
    <qTrib>409.8400</qTrib>
    <vUnTrib>1.9600000000</vUnTrib>
    <indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
+<imposto>
</det>
-<det nItem="2">
  -<prod>
    <cProd>176</cProd>
    <cEAN>SEM GTIN</cEAN>
    <xProd>SCH1</xProd>
    <NCM>96072000</NCM>
    <CFOP>6102</CFOP>
    <uCom>MT</uCom>
```

Assim, tendo a estrutura acima, preciso pegar os valores de cada Tag para cada item que existir no XML.

Estou tentando algo do tipo:

````
 //itens da nota!!!!  LAÇO
        Numero_Itens := XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('det');  //CONTA QUANTOS ITEMS POSSUI NO XML
        atributo := ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].AttributeNodes['nItem'].Text; //pega o atributo da tag det
        Item := 1; //Inicializa no Primeiro Item
        //Memo1.Lines.Add('6- - - - - - - - - - - - - ITENS DA NOTA- - - - - - - - - -');
        //While Item <= Numero_Itens.length do
        For Item := 1 to Numero_Itens.length do
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('6- - - - - - - - - - - - - ITENS DA NOTA- - - - - - - - - -');
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['cProd'].Text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['cEAN'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['xProd'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['NCM'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['CFOP'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['uCom'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['qCom'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['vUnCom'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['vProd'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['cEANTrib'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['uTrib'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['qTrib'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['vUnTrib'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['prod'].ChildNodes['indTot'].text);

          //imposto
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['ICMS'].ChildNodes['ICMSSN102'].ChildNodes['orig'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['ICMS'].ChildNodes['ICMSSN102'].ChildNodes['CSOSN'].text);

          //pis
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['PIS'].ChildNodes['PISOutr'].ChildNodes['CST'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['PIS'].ChildNodes['PISOutr'].ChildNodes['vBC'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['PIS'].ChildNodes['PISOutr'].ChildNodes['pPIS'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['PIS'].ChildNodes['PISOutr'].ChildNodes['vPIS'].text);

          //COFINS
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['COFINS'].ChildNodes['COFINSOutr'].ChildNodes['CST'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['COFINS'].ChildNodes['COFINSOutr'].ChildNodes['vBC'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['COFINS'].ChildNodes['COFINSOutr'].ChildNodes['pCOFINS'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['infNFe'].ChildNodes['det'].ChildNodes['imposto'].ChildNodes['COFINS'].ChildNodes['COFINSOutr'].ChildNodes['vCOFINS'].text);
          Memo1.Lines.Add('6- - - - - - - - - - - - - FIM ITENS DA NOTA- - - - - - - - - -');
          //Item := Item + 1;
          NextSibling;
        end;```


No código acima ele apenas lê todos os valores de cada tag descrita no código, porém apenas para o primeiro item. Não sei como criar a iteração entre os itens, referenciando-os pelas Tags nItem 1,2 e assim por diante.

Eu não sei como usar o comando NextSibling, e estou pegando os valores e escrevendo-os no Memo1, apenas.

Muito Obrigado!
````

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão de código para testes onde é utilizada a propriedade ChildNodes.Count para obter a quantidade de nós filhos para interagir por eles, e com o comando With / Do são acessados os nós filhos sucessivamente:

```
with ChildNodes['infNFe'] do
  for Item := 1 to ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    if ChildNodes[Item].NodeName = 'det' then
      with ChildNodes[Item] do
        begin
          with ChildNodes['prod'] do
            begin
              Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['cProd'].Text);
              Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['cEAN'].text);
              Memo1.Lines.Add(ChildNodes['xProd'].text);
              // ...
            end;
          // ...
        end;
```

Comment: Cirúrgico, imex.
Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Eu acho mais fácil a leitura pelo componente gratuito do ACBr (ACBrNFe).
Importação do arquivo:

```delphi
function TDmProdutoXML.ImportarXML(const pCaminhoXML: string; out pMsg: string): Boolean;
var
  vXML: TStringList;
begin
  // importar conteudo XML
  vXML := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      vXML.LoadFromFile(pCaminhoXML);
      // converter para padrao UTF8 caso nao seja
      if (XmlEhUTF8(vXML.Text) = False) then
        vXML.Text := UTF8ToString(vXML.Text);

      // importar dados XML para componente
      ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Clear;
      ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.LoadFromString(vXML.Text);
      pMsg := 'Arquivo importado com sucesso!';
      Result := True;
    except
      pMsg := 'Arquivo NFe Inválido!';
      Exit(False);
    end;
  finally
    vXML.DisposeOf;
  end;  
end;
```

E para ler os itens, basta fazer um loop no componente após a importação, lendo os dados que forem do seu interesse, abaixo um fragmento da leitura os itens:

```delphi
for I := 0 to Pred(ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Count) do
begin
  // dados basicos
  fdmTblProdutos.Append;     
  fdmTblProdutosCODIGO.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.cProd;
  fdmTblProdutosCOD_BARRAS.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.cEAN;
  fdmTblProdutosDESCRICAO.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.xProd;
  fdmTblProdutosNCM.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.NCM;
  fdmTblProdutosVALOR_UNITARIO.AsFloat := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.vUnCom;
  fdmTblProdutosQUANTIDADE.AsFloat := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.qCom;
  fdmTblProdutosDESCONTO.AsFloat := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.vDesc;
  fdmTblProdutosNUM_ITEM.AsInteger := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.nItem;
  fdmTblProdutosCFOP.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.CFOP;
  fdmTblProdutosUNIDADE.AsString := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.uCom;
  fdmTblProdutosTOTAL_ITEM.AsFloat := ACBrNFe.NotasFiscais.Items[0].NFe.Det.Items[I].Prod.vProd;
  try
    fdmTblProdutos.Post;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      pMsg := 'Não foi possível ler os itens da NFe!' + sLineBreak + 'Problema(s) encontrado(s):' + sLineBreak + E.Message;
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```